# Sum all columns in a Pandas DataFrame where there are non-numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [12,3,4,5,'a',5], 'col2' : [1,5,'b',6,10,1]})
```

If I run `df.sum(axis=0, numeric_only=True)`, I get the following output:

```
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

However, if I change the non-numeric values to `None` then it works fine.

So, my question is how can I find the sums of all the columns in my dataset when there are non-numeric values present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `apply` because `to_numeric` works only with columns (`Series`):

```
print (df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum())
#same as
#print (df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).sum())
col1    29.0
col2    23.0
dtype: float64
```

Another solution is `concat` with `list comprehension`:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce') for col in df], axis=1).sum()
print (df)
col1    29.0
col2    23.0
dtype: float64
```

If only few columns faster is repeat code:

```
df.col1 = pd.to_numeric(df.col1, errors='coerce')
df.col2 = pd.to_numeric(df.col2, errors='coerce')
print (df.sum())
col1    29.0
col2    23.0
dtype: float64
```

I think `numeric_only=True` doesnt work for columns for mixed content - numeric with string values.

Sample - `col1` is numeric and `col2` is non numeric:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,3,4], 'col2' : ['1','5','b']})
print (df)
   col1 col2
0     1    1
1     3    5
2     4    b

print (df.sum(numeric_only=True))
col1    8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: jezrael the Kung fu Panda :)

Comment: Thanks but let's say I have a df with a large number of columns and I wanted to programmatically do this?

Comment: First solution does not work? `(df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).sum())` ?